# Checking blank field in text area

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 text box and 1 textarea field.
id, name, address, contact.
All are java scripted in the purpose of checking blank field.
I did it in this way :

javascript code :

```
function checkForm()    
{
var id=document.getElementById("id").value;
var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
var address=document.getElementById("address").value;
var contact=document.getElementById("contact").value;


if(id.length<1 )        
{
alert("Please enter all the informations!");
return false;
}
if(name.length<1 )      
{
alert("Please enter the name!");
return false;
}
if(address.length<1 )       
{
alert("Please enter the address!");
return false;
}
if(contact.length<1 )       
{
alert("Please enter the contact!");
return false;
}
```

html code :

```
<form method="post" action="clients.php" onSubmit="return checkForm()">
  id <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
  name <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  address <textarea name="address" id="address"> </textarea>
  contact <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

All are working except textarea. I am trying with some other code, founded in the internet, but those aren't working. Maintaining the serial (id then name then address then contact....) how can i check the blank space of the textarea?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use trim function to remove whitespaces

```
var id=document.getElementById("id").value.trim();
var name=document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
var address=document.getElementById("address").value.trim();
var contact=document.getElementById("contact").value.trim();
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. Using "innnerHTML" , the javascript only check for the 1st two entry. @Ankit

Comment: Yup!!....it does. I have to change only the var address=document.getElementById("address").value.trim();
Thanks a lot by the way.........
have a nice day....Ankit Gautam :) :) :)

Comment: no do it for all the field to prevent user from entering white space by pressing space bar